# Java read certain line from txt file

Tags: java, file, text, io

I want to read the 2nd line of text from a file and have that put into an array. I already have it working on the first line.

```
        [ Code removed as requested ]
```

The while loop above shows how I read and save the 1st line of the text file into an array. I wish to repeat this process from the 2nd line only into a different array.

### File Content:

Sofa,Armchair,Computer Desk,Coffee Table,TV Stand,Cushion,Bed,Mattress,Duvet,Pillow
599.99,229.99,129.99,40.00,37.00,08.00,145.00,299.99,24.99,09.99

Comment: Swing code isn't relevant to a question about reading files. Please remove it.

Comment: You won't get help by either posting a lot of irrelevant code or by removing the relevant code, or by abusing people who are trying to help you. You've also overlooked that I *have* also answered your question, but now that you've removed all the code it is impossible to help you further. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the first readLine() call, and move the String.split() call into the loop.

Comment: Then would I use the for loop to seperate the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the BufferedReader class to read the entire file and then manipulate the String output.

Something along these lines

```
public static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String toReturn = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            toReturn = toReturn+"\n"+sCurrentLine;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

would yield a String which can then be easily used.

Comment: Thanks :) Think I can do it from this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String filePath = args[0];
    String[] lineElements = getLine(filePath,2).split(",");
}

public static String getLine(String path,int line)
{
    List<String> cases = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        String currLine = "";
        while((currLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            cases.add(currLine);
        }
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cases.get(line - 1);//2nd line
}
```